# BOOST_LOG_TRIVIAL vs logrotate (reopen log)

Tags: c++, linux, boost, logrotate

I have a program that is running as a service for a long time. I use `BOOST_LOG_TRIVIAL(info) << "Message"` for logging various events. I would like to cooperate with `logrotate` and reopen my log file after rotation. In theory the screenplay works as follows:

- My program starts, some logging happens
- Log is renamed from `something.log` to `something.log.1` by an other program like `logrotate` or by me manually.
- My program continues to log to the `something.log.1` file.
- I send SIGHUP (or something) to my program so I can reopen the log file. But I don't know how to.

My prepared example so far (may not be necessary):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdexcept>

#include <csignal>

#include <boost/thread.hpp>
#include <boost/chrono.hpp>
#include <boost/log/trivial.hpp>
#include <boost/log/expressions.hpp>
#include <boost/log/sources/severity_logger.hpp>
#include <boost/log/sources/record_ostream.hpp>
#include <boost/log/utility/setup/file.hpp>
#include <boost/log/utility/setup/console.hpp>
#include <boost/log/utility/setup/common_attributes.hpp>
#include <boost/log/support/date_time.hpp>

inline
void setupLogging(std::string const &logFileName)
{
  namespace logging = boost::log;
  namespace src = boost::log::sources;
  namespace expr = boost::log::expressions;
  namespace keywords = boost::log::keywords;
  logging::add_common_attributes();
  auto format = expr::stream
    << expr::format_date_time< boost::posix_time::ptime >("TimeStamp", "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f")
    << " progname " << logging::trivial::severity
    << ": " << expr::smessage;
  auto fileOutput = logging::add_file_log(
      keywords::file_name = logFileName, keywords::format = format
      , keywords::auto_flush = true, keywords::open_mode = std::ios::app
    );
  auto consoleOutput = logging::add_console_log(
    std::cerr, keywords::format = format, keywords::auto_flush = true
  );
  BOOST_LOG_TRIVIAL(debug) << "CHECKPOINT @ setupLogging() after log initialization.";
}

void my_signal_handler(int signal)
{
  BOOST_LOG_TRIVIAL(info) << "my_signal_handler BEGIN";
  /* REOPEN LOG HERE */
  BOOST_LOG_TRIVIAL(info) << "my_signal_handler END";
}

int main()
{
  setupLogging("logrotate.test.log");
  if(signal(SIGHUP, my_signal_handler) == SIG_ERR)
  {
    BOOST_LOG_TRIVIAL(error) << "Failed to register signal handler";
    return 1;
  } else
    BOOST_LOG_TRIVIAL(info) << "Signal handler registered.";
  BOOST_LOG_TRIVIAL(info) << "CHECKPOINT 0";
  for(size_t i=1; i<100; ++i)
  {
    boost::this_thread::sleep_for( boost::chrono::seconds(1) );
    BOOST_LOG_TRIVIAL(info) << "CHECKPOINT " << i;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Compiling:

```
LINK="-lboost_system -lboost_date_time -lboost_log -lboost_log_setup -lboost_thread -lboost_chrono -lpthread"
g++ -std=c++11 -Wextra -DBOOST_LOG_DYN_LINK -pedantic -O3 logrotate_test.cpp -o logrotate_test $LINK
```

**Source code representation of Adam's answer**

```
namespace detail666777888
{
       using namespace boost;
       using namespace boost::log;
       typedef shared_ptr< sinks::synchronous_sink< sinks::text_file_backend > > T;
}
typedef detail666777888::T SPFileSink;
SPFileSink logFileSink;

void setupLogging(...){
... logFileSink = logging::add_file_log ...
}

void my_sighup_handler(int /*signal*/)
{
  BOOST_LOG_TRIVIAL(info) << "my_sighup_handler START";
  auto oldLFS = logFileSink;
  setupLogging("logrotate.test.log");
  boost::log::core::get()->remove_sink(oldLFS);
  BOOST_LOG_TRIVIAL(info) << "my_sighup_handler FINISH";
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use *copytruncate* logrotate option.

From manual:

> Truncate the original log file in place after creating a copy, instead
>   of moving the old log file and optionally creating a new one. It can
>   be used when some program cannot be told to close its logfile and thus
>   might continue writing (appending) to the previous log file forever.
>   Note that there is a very small time slice between copying the file
>   and truncating it, so some logging data might be lost. When this
>   option is used, the create option will have no effect, as the old log
>   file stays in place.

http://linux.die.net/man/8/logrotate

**EDIT:**

Try this. Take a look at *add_file_log*[1] function source code. Then:

1. remember the object you have added with add_file_log (it returns sink)
2. when you receive the signal *remove_sink*[2] and add new one sink with *add_file_log*[1] -- (logs entries may leak when they are generated by other thread)

[1] http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/boost/log/utility/setup/file.hpp

[2] http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/boost/log/core/core.hpp

Comment: Thank you for this workaround. But I'm hoping for a solution. If everything else fails this will be the winner. :-)

Comment: Adding the new sink, first and removing the old after makes sure that data will not be lost. But there is a chance of data appearing in both files. Which is acceptable for me. :-)

Answer (score 2):

I was facing the same problem and found a quite straightforward solution: Just initialize the `text_file_backend` with a single filename (no pattern whatsoever) and call `text_file_backend::rotate_file()`. This will close the current file and open a new one with the same name.

```
// create sink
auto backend = boost::make_shared< boost::log::sinks::text_file_backend >(
        boost::log::keywords::file_name = "my.log",
        boost::log::keywords::open_mode = std::ios_base::out | std::ios_base::app
);
auto sink = boost::make_shared<sinks::synchronous_sink<boost::log::sinks::text_file_backend>>(backend);
boost::log::core::get()->add_sink(sink);

// ... do some logging

// move log file and...
// reopen log file
sink->locked_backend()->rotate_file();

// ... do more logging
```

I open the log file with `std::ios_base::app` to prevent the logfile from being truncated if the file exists.

This solution has the advantage that no files need to be copied and log records will neither be lost nor duplicated.